# ReactJS and DraftJS, how to change font size on the fly?

Tags: reactjs, wysiwyg, draftjs

I have the following code that works perfectly for italic, bold and underline:

```
    onUnderlineClick = () => {
        this.onChange(
            RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(this.state.editorState, "UNDERLINE")
        );
    };

    onBoldClick = () => {
        this.onChange(RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(this.state.editorState, "BOLD"));
    };

    onItalicClick = () => {
        this.onChange(
            RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(this.state.editorState, "ITALIC")
        );
    };
```

Now I would like to add a button that changes the font size, I tried with:

```
  onHeaderClick = () => {
       this.onChange(RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(this.state.editorState, '30px'));
  };
```

But it doesn't work... how can I change the font size of the selected text?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a custom inline style

```
const inlineStyles = [
  { label: "B", style: "BOLD" },
  { label: "I", style: "ITALIC" },
  { label: "U", style: "UNDERLINE" },
  { label: "<strike>S</strike> ", style: "STRIKETHROUGH" },
  { label: "I am your header", style: "FONT_SIZE_30" }
];
```

and use it to build a menu

Second, you need to define a custom style map

```
const customStyleMap = {
  STRIKETHROUGH: {
    textDecoration: "line-through"
  },
  FONT_SIZE_30: {
    fontSize: "30px"
  }
};
```

and pass it:

```
class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  // ...
  render() {
    return (
      <Editor
        customStyleMap={styleMap}
        editorState={this.state.editorState}
        ...
      />
    );
  }
}
```

See full example on Codesanbox https://codesandbox.io/s/font-size-inline-we2q2

DraftJS Inline styles docs https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-inline-styles

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work in your case

```
toggleFontSize = fontSize => {
   const { editorState } = this.state;
   RichUtils.toggleBlockType( editorState, fontSize  );
}

<button onClick={e => this.toggleFontSize('100px')}>100px</button>
```

For more explanation please check - https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-custom-styles#api

In documentation, they have given an example

```
toggleFontSize = fontSize => {
  const newEditorState = styles.fontSize.toggle(this.state.editorState, 
  fontSize);

  return this.updateEditorState(newEditorState);
};
```

Comment: Have you checked the example given in docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-custom-styles#api?